# How to use apex ids within jquery functions

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I want to fade out my `apex:pagemessage` when I click anywhere on the window. For that jquery gives a simple way :

```
$(window).click(function(){$("#id").fadeOut();});
```

But here I am not able to use the `<apex:pagemessage>` id within my jquery. How can I access this element?

```
<apex:page extensions="arema"> 
    <script>
        $(window).click(function(){$("#showmsg").fadeOut();});
    </script>
    <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>  
    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveTemplate}" value="Show Message"  rerender="showmsg"/>
</apex:page>
```

---

Apex class

```
global class arema{
    public void saveTemplate()
    {   
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Saved changes successfully'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Rahul I have updated my question clearly. Please look

Comment: Time to debug. Ensure that the selector is working by logging it. If it is then you will need to debug the JS and event handlers. Try to hide it from the JS console in the browser using the real Id of the element.

Comment: @Aruna, the bellow answer seems more than appropriate, however, you seem to keep bumping into other issues which are/were not described in your Original post, if possible, please select an answer, and open a new post pointing towards any other issue you might be encountering rather than following up in the comments. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

VF adds to the Ids if not all elements has an id. It will be like `jd_0.showmsg`

So use a `Ends With` selector as below

```
$("[id$=showmsg]")
```

Did you include jQuery?

The following works fine for me:

**Class**

```
global class arema{
    public arema(){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new   ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Saved changes successfully'));
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="arema"> 
        <script>
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
          $(window).click(function(){
                $("[id$=showmsg]").fadeOut();
            });
        </script>
      <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>  

     </apex:page>
```

Comment: Eric, I did like u said but my apex:pagemessage is not fading with window click .

Comment: I gave an alert within my jquery function and the alert message is coming with the button click not with window click also the messaging is not fading.

Comment: It is dissapering? If so then if you are having issues with the fade that would be better asked on SO. The above example works. How the message get there initially is irrelevant

Comment: The message is disappearing now, but it works only when I click on the borders of window. When I click on content area or edit the contents the message is not fading.

Comment: Then you have other things in play you have not posted. The example works for me when I click anywhere.

Comment: I am having a composer section in the visualforce page. Whenever I make changes to the contents within the composer I want the apex:pagemessage to be faded. For that I opted window click jquery function. But the window click function is not working within the composer where I needed it the most.